# What is the plot id/flag for the survival of the grissom academy students in mass effect 3 for the ME 3 editor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

At the very end of [Jack's mission at Grissom Academy](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Grissom_Academy:_Emergency_Evacuation), you choose whether to send the students on the front lines, or use them as support roles. Sending them to the front line has them killed at the end, but they live if they're support roles.

If anyone knows the plot flag or id to do this, it'd be really helpful

Comment: Welcome to the site Dman. Nice clear first question. Good work! Does ME3 name the quests? Might be nice to add the name of the quest here. That makes it easier for other people to later find this question.

Comment: how do you know they are killed at the end? i have played the game over about 4 times and not once has it been seen that they died, or lived at that, i do know if put at the front lines, they will be doing hit and runs, talked to jack in nightclub, they all seem to be alive then, about 80% way through game, This is not having a go, incase some people think i am, merely curious to see why he thinks that. thank you

Comment: @monkeyman1188 If you have the extended cut, Jack will either be with the class if support role or mourning at their graves if front lines. http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Grissom_Academy:_Emergency_Evacuation in the aftermath section

Answer (score 1):

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zv8mxcxs

This is a list of all plot flags/IDs as found at http://forum.bioware.com/topic/306020-mass-effect-3-modding-thread-last-update-14-05-2012/. I'm having trouble deciphering which one points to Jack's mission though. I'm guessing it's OmgJck, but I have little to back that up other than "Jck" in the name.

Answer (score -2):

The students in Grissom Academy serve as "War Assets". (I'm sure you've heard of "War Assets" in ME3). Anything or anyone you can ask to join your cause in repelling the Reaper invasion from Earth. The students will affect (not sure if greatly or minimal) the outcome of your Reaper repelling on Earth in the end of the game.